# Nested objects in my rails JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want to create a nested JSON format which looks something like this for my `Event` model.

```
"event"   {
  "quiz": {
    "name": "",
    "desc": "",
    "events"[
   {
    "name": "general quiz",
    "desc": ""
    }]

  "dance":{
    "name":"",
    "desc":"",
    "events"[{
    "name":"solo dance",
    "desc":""
    }]
   }
```

essentially, i want my `events` to be categorized into actual events under the name `quiz`, `dance`, etc, and each of them will have separate events like solo,group dance etc. Any tips on how I can do this (with or without jbuilder)

Comment: Your events are stored in the database? Acquired from an API? How do you distinguish between "quiz", "dance" ... You need to give us a little more information to work with here. A simple approach: build a hash and then call `to_json` on it.

Comment: events are stored in the database. I want to nest "quiz", "dance" as child objects inside the parent event model.

Comment: Please remember: just because things are clear to you, they are not to anybody reading your question. Are "events" stored in a single table, then how will we know which events are dances/quizes? Are they stored in separate tables? Can you show us how your models/associations look? Or the events is just an abstract example, and you do not really care about the iteration over the events and the decision process, you just need to know how to build a json with an extra level of indirection?

Comment: The latter. I do not care about the iteration over the events. I just need separate categories, all capable of holding various events relevant to that category. It's more a question of figuring out the structure..

Answer (score 1):

So the simplest approach imho is just build a hash-structure looking like you want your json to look and then convert the hash to json.

So, for the example let's iterate over events and assume each event knows how to convert itself to json:

Simple approach:

```
events_hash = { "quizes": [], "dances": []}
events.each do |event| 
  event_type = event.quiz? ? "quizes" : "dances"
  events_hash[event_type] << event.to_json 
end 
events_hash.to_json
```

This should get you started.

(I simplified your json structure for the example)

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have all models & relationships properly defined, take a look at serializers.

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers